Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve modification time path = 'C:/test\myNextApp'
I am running Dart/Flutter on windows.
I defined the string variable as follows:
String mypath = 'C:/test';

For some reason, I cannot define it like this with the forward slash - windows does not recognize the forward slash and the letter t:
String mypath = 'C:\test';

From the error, it is clear that the program mixes forward and backslash that is not correct.
Could you please advise how to address this issue.
Thank You

You can declare the path in two normal ways using slashes:
Forward Slash (/):
String mypath = 'C:/test/myNextApp';

Escaped Backslash (\):
String mypath = 'C:\\test\\myNextApp';

Use any one slash. don't mix-up.
You Can’t Use "\" Directly, if you type a single backslash in a string, Dart assumes it's the start of an escape sequence. This can lead to unexpected results or errors if it’s not followed by a valid escape sequence character.
These are special char or escape sequences
\t – Tab,
\\ – A single backslash
So use double forward slash(resulted in one), if you want to use forward slash inside any string.
Additionally, for declaring any string containing any path you can use following method also:
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

void main() {
  String mypath = path.join('C:', 'test', 'myNextApp');
  // Value of my path is now: mypath = "C:\test\myNextApp"
}

